# Pass array to component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I'm getting a problem trying to send an array that I get from my DB, from a component to another.
I mean, I'm obtaining JSON data and then that data has to be passed to another component.
I was thinking about using the map method.
I checked my console and I noticed that I get the correct data from the DB but when I'm trying to send it by the state, in the class that I want to get the info is null
Class which gets the objects:

```
import React from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import MovieList from './MovieList'
import MoviesService from '../services/MoviesService'

class MovieListGet extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      movies: []
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount () {
    await this._getMovies()
  }

  async _getMovies () {
    const response = await MoviesService.getMovies()
    this.setState({ movies: response.data })
    console.log(this.state.movies)
  }

  async _deleteMovie (id) {
  }

  _navigateToCreateMovies () {
    // Adrress
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <MovieList
          movies = {this.state.movies}
          onCreateMovie={this._navigateToCreateMovies.bind(this)}
          onDelete={this._deleteMovie.bind(this)}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(MovieListGet)
```

Class that has to get the array

```
/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
import React from 'react'
import {...} from '@material-ui/core'
import { ... } from '@material-ui/icons'

class MovieList extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    const { movies } = props

    this.state = {
      _movies: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    console.log(this.props.movie)
    this.setState({ _movies: this.props.movies })
  }

  _renderMovies () {
    if (!this.state._movies || this.state._movies.length < 1) {
      return (
        // Something
      )
    } else {
      return this.state._movies.map(m => (
        // something
      )
      )
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      // Something
    )
  }
}

export default (MovieList)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MoviesListGet should pass the prop like this:

```
   <MovieList
      movies={this.state.movies}
      onCreateMovie={this._navigateToCreateMovies.bind(this)}
      onDelete={this._deleteMovie.bind(this)}
    />
```

Then in MoviesList component you can use it like this in you renderMovies method:

```
class MovieList extends React.Component {
    renderMovies () {
      if (!this.props.movies || this.props.movies.length < 1) {
        return (
          // Something
        )
      } else {
        return this.props.movies.map(m => (
          // something
        )
        )
      }
    }

    render () {
      return (
        // Something
      )
    }
  }

  export default MovieList;
```

Comment: The problem here, is that 'movies' is not defined, should I use it as a global variable?

Comment: True, I modified it, no, you need to use movies from the state. I have just edited the answer!

Comment: Following your suggestion, if I do console.log(this.props.movies) it is undefined :/

Comment: Can you create a livecode so I can check it? You might have something in your code that is breaking it

Comment: Edited again! MovieList component should work now mate

Comment: Sorry, it is still as undefined when I use the console log

Comment: I cant create a snippet because the db is in my local machine

Comment: If you can do a snippet mocking the response I will be happy to help

Comment: What is the value of movies?

Comment: Now working just a stupid mistake on the render, forgot to put props instead of state.
Thanks for the help, you just saved me

Comment: No worries mate. Just make sure to mark the response as correct!